# The 8 day review week

Tags: bug, review

I was checking my progress in the review queue's and discovered that they're looking at an 8 day windows to report the weekly review total.  160 reviews at 20 reviews/day is 8 days of activity not 7.

This is from the Low Quality Review queue on StackOverflow.  I get the same for Suggested Edits; the other queues I either don't have enough reviews to see anything obviously wrong with the total or don't have access to at all.

[image]

Comment: Which review queue?

Comment: Weird how it's counting 160 for the month too. We're only on the 7th day of this month... Like... Where would it get the 8th day from in the first place?

Comment: @animuson I assume that the month is a (30 day??) rolling window and the total reflects that I restarted reviewing after an extended hiatus 8 days ago.

Comment: Ah, perhaps it is. I can never remember which counts reset instantly at a new month and which ones roll over 30 days. Needs more consistency. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure I agree.  That one appears to just be an observation of a rolling window instead of a fixed 7 day one.  (And is different from the bug that its poster said it was a recurrence of (week/month totals being the same as lifetime.))

Comment: @Dan I think the reason behind the scenes is the same, some counter/cache did not reset in time.

Comment: An SE week is 6-8 days...